# Novoda Download Manager, how to set download complete listener

Tags: android-download-manager

I needed to download files in private application storage. Since Androids Download manager is not able to do that I am using this library:

https://github.com/novoda/download-manager

I can start the download, but I am do not get broadcast when the download is complete. Has anyone used this library and can help.

This is how I sent the listener right now:

```
 private void setupDownloadingExample() {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(BIG_FILE);
    final Request request = new Request(uri)
            .setDestinationInInternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES, "penguins.dat")
            .setNotificationVisibility(NotificationVisibility.ACTIVE_OR_COMPLETE)
            .setTitle("Family of Penguins")
            .setDescription("These are not the beards you're looking for")
            .setBigPictureUrl(PENGUINS_IMAGE);

    findViewById(R.id.main_download_button).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull View v) {
                    onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    };
                    (MainActivity.this).registerReceiver(onComplete,
                            new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
                    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                }
            });
}
```

The code snippet is from the example provided by the library.

Answer (score 0):

From the demo inside the repo, you need to use a Broadcast receiver to listen for Download events:

https://github.com/novoda/download-manager/tree/master/demo-extended

Register in your manifest like this:

https://github.com/novoda/download-manager/blob/master/demo-extended/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L63-L69

```
<receiver
  android:name="com.novoda.downloadmanager.demo.extended.DownloadBatchStartedReceiver"
  android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.novoda.downloadmanager.action.BATCH_FIRST_TIME_START" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then you can listen for download completed:

https://github.com/novoda/download-manager/blob/master/demo-extended/src/main/java/com/novoda/downloadmanager/demo/extended/DownloadBatchStartedReceiver.java

```
public class DownloadBatchCompletionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final int UNKNOWN_BATCH_ID = -1;
    private static final String TAG = DownloadBatchCompletionReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
        long batchId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_BATCH_ID, UNKNOWN_BATCH_ID);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Batch completed with id: " + batchId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Batch completed: " + batchId);
    }

}
```

All downloads are treated as a batch, even if its just 1 file downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I should be able to work on this soon